# SAPUI5: Get all Components present in the current window

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, component.js

I know that you can get a single Component with:

```
sap.ui.component("ComponentID");
```

But is there also a way to list all components that live in the current window context?

Thx
Chris

Answer (score 1):

`sap.ui.component(string)` delegates to `sap.ui.getCore().getComponent()`. With that you can query a specific component by id.

There at the `sap.ui.core.Core` is a [registry of components](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/rel-1.36/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/core/Core.js#L161). But its marked as private and even has a TODO to get rid of it. So i would advice to not access that directly.

Comment: Not only is it not recommendable to use this registry it is not accessible from sap.ui.getCore()...

Answer (score 1):

You can get the available components through [Component.registry](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ui.core.Component.registry).

```js
> sap.ui.core.Component.registry.all()
{component-name: fnClass}

// You can use Object.keys to get the names
> Object.keys(sap.ui.core.Component.registry.all())
['component-name']
```

And then you can use this name to fetch the actual component, either through [Core.getComponent](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ui.core.Core%23methods/getComponent), [Component.get](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ui.core.Component%23methods/sap.ui.core.Component.get) or [Componeny.registry.get](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ui.core.Component.registry%23methods/sap.ui.core.Component.registry.get) (and i wouldn't even be surprised if where a dozen other options in the documentation).

```js
> sap.ui.getCore().getComponent("component-name") // pre 1.95
> sap.ui.core.Component.get("component-name") // post 1.95
fnClass {_oMetadataProxy: UIComponentMetadata, _oManifest: constructor, _mManifestModels: {…}, _mServices: {…}, getMetadata: ƒ, …}
```